# Why are my testflight betas not getting invited?

Tags: ios, testflight

I'm using TestFlight to test an iOS app.  For my first testable version I only invited 5 friends, of which only 2 installed the app.  I'm not sure if the others got the email but I just assumed they did and ignored it.

Yesterday I submitted a new version and invited another 10 or so people.  I noticed today that only the original 2 people installed the new app so I contacted 3 or 4 of the new testers and nobody has seen an email invite yet.

I read that turning off testflight, then turning it back on, would force emails to be sent.  I tried that, still no joy.

Am I missing something?  I have a hard time believing this is a TestFlight bug or we'd be hearing a lot more about it, right?

I see a similar question was closed as "not about programming".  But this is very much about the iOS development process... I can't "program" an iOS app without getting it out for testing.

Comment: closing for "not about programming" just means, it does not belong to stackoverflow, but to one of the other sides. And I also getting always this problem. Unselect the users, save, select, save again. That's the way it worked for me.

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit new at this TestFlight stuff... how does one "unselect the users"?  Thanks much for your response!

Comment: Nevermind, figured it out... but not sure any invites were still sent out :(

Comment: I added one of my other email addresses for test-reasons. never can be sure, that everyone got the mail, have to ask one by one ^^ but if you got none, than there is a possibility, that the others also have not - and the other way round. But this is a problem I am facing everytime again with apple...

Comment: After I wrote this, my users eventually got invited (I did the switching on and off thing, etc).  But then I pushed another version to TestFlight Saturday night, and as of right now (Monday afternoon) no invites were sent, even though users can get the update in their TestFlight app if they find out it's there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends where you add the users...

1. If you add them through "Users & Roles>TestFlight Beta Testers>External" then they are invited to test the app but not invited to the pre-release build.
2. If you add them through "My Apps>Your app name>Prerelease>External Testers" and tap + then you can choose to "Add New Testers" which both invites new testers to your app and adds them to the pre-release.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can add additional testers (as far as I've seen) is to update your tester list, and then upload a new binary.  In other words, I don't believe you can modify the tester list on a build that's already actively being tested.